# What will the Frenchman say?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, knowledge, language

An Englishman, a Frenchman and a German are speaking.

> First the Englishman says : "M".
>
> Then the Frenchman says : "M" as well.
>
> And the German also says : "M".

They all agree and decide to change the order.

> The German says : "D".
>
> The Frenchman says : "V".
>
> And the Englishman says : "S".

They agree again and change the order. The Frenchman will be the first to speak.

**What will the Frenchman say?**

The expected answer is just a letter, but, to be accepted, explanations will be needed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the French will say

> D for Dimanche (Sunday in French)

The English says "M", the French says "M", the German says "M"

> Monday, Mardi (Tuesday in French), Mittwoch (Wednesday in German)

German "D",  French "V", English "S"

> Donnerstag (Thursday in German), Vendredi (Friday in French), Saturday